# Is it possible to subscript a SortedList<DateTime,decimal[]> to get its values objects by name?

Tags: c#

When I load data from a CSV file I create a `DataPoint` object for each row of data:

```
public class DataPoint
{
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public Decimal Open {get; set;}
    public Decimal High {get; set;}
    public Decimal Low {get; set;}
    public Decimal Close {get; set;}
}
```

Then I add each `DataPoint` in a `TimeSeries` object, which is nothing more than a `SortedList<DateTime, decimal[]>`:

```
public class TimeSeries: SortedList<DateTime,decimal[]>
{
  public void Add(DataPoint dataPoint)
  {
      var prices = new decimal[]{dataPoint.Open, dataPoint.High, dataPoint.Low, dataPoint.Close};
      this.Add(dataPoint.Date,prices);
  }
}
```

If I want to write in the Console the `Date` and the `Close` of each record in my `TimeSeries`, now I  do something like this:

```
var timeSeries = Load(filename); // Load the data

foreach(var dp in timeSeries)
{
  WriteLine($"{dp.Key}, {dp.Values[4]}");
}
```

But I'd like to be able to do it like this:

```
var timeSeries = Load(filename); // Load the data

foreach(var dp in timeSeries)
{
  WriteLine($"{dp.Date}, {dp.Close}");
}
```

Is there a way to subscript the `TimeSeries` object to accomplish this?

Would it be better to have a `TimeSeries<DateTime,DataPoint>` instead of `TimeSeries<DateTime, decimal[]>` I used to not replicate the field used as key?

Comment: Answer to last question: yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to encapsulate collection field then use inheritance:

```
public class TimeSeries
{
    private readonly SortedList<DateTime, DataPoint> internalCollection = new SortedList<DateTime, DataPoint>();

    public void Add(DataPoint dataPoint)
    {
        internalCollection.Add(dataPoint.Date, dataPoint);
    }

    public IEnumerator<DataPoint> GetEnumerator()
    {    
        foreach(var point in internalCollection)
        {
            yield return point.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to do:

```
TimeSeries timeSeries = DataLoader.LoadData();

foreach(var dataPoint in timeSeries)
{
    WriteLine($"{dataPoint.Date}, {dataPoint.Close}");
}
```